# How to write an update query with some joins between tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, updating

How do I write an update query for this SQL (Oracle) I just wrote below, I would like 
to do an  update as follows which uses multiple tables (3 of them):

```
   update payroll.emp_appointments
   set e.sales=w.sales
   where the details below

   select w.storecode,w.salespersoncode,w.sumsales,w.truncateddate, c.customerid, 
   e.firstname,e.lastname,c.contactid
   from weekstat w, sysdba.contact_retail c, payroll.emp_appointments e where 
   c.customerid=w.customerid
   and cast(w.salespersoncode  as char(6))=e.emp_num
   and trunc(e.tradingdate)=w.truncateddate
   and e.contactid=c.contactid
   and e.storecode=cast(e.storecode as varchar2(6))
   and e.sales=0.00
   and e.tradingdate > sysdate-10
```

I tried doing the following after creating a temp table but it seems to update all the rows in the emp_appointments table which I don't want to do:

```
   update payroll.emp_appointments e
   set e.sales= (
   select ue.sumsales
   from update_emp_sales_temp ue
   where e.contactid=ue.contactid and
   e.emp_num=ue.salespersoncode and 
   e.storecode=ue.storecode and
   e.firstname=ue.firstname and 
   e.lastname=ue.lastname and
   trunc(e.tradingdate)=ue.truncateddate)
   where e.tradingdate>sysdate-30;
```

Answer (score 0):

it easier to remember construction

```
update <select with all the joins> set <set conditions>
```

in your case:

```
UPDATE
(select w.sales src, e.sales dst
from weekstat w, sysdba.contact_retail c, payroll.emp_appointments e where 
c.customerid=w.customerid
and cast(w.salespersoncode  as char(6))=e.emp_num
and trunc(e.tradingdate)=w.truncateddate
and e.contactid=c.contactid
and e.storecode=cast(e.storecode as varchar2(6))
and e.sales=0.00
and e.tradingdate > sysdate-10)
SET dst = src
```

just remember that you need to update only one table

---

Another aproach using MERGE:

```
MERGE INTO payroll.emp_appointments e
USING (select w.sales, e.emp_num
from weekstat w, sysdba.contact_retail c, payroll.emp_appointments e where 
c.customerid=w.customerid
and cast(w.salespersoncode  as char(6))=e.emp_num
and trunc(e.tradingdate)=w.truncateddate
and e.contactid=c.contactid
and e.storecode=cast(e.storecode as varchar2(6))
and e.sales=0.00
and e.tradingdate > sysdate-10) subquery
ON (e.emp_num = subquery.emp_num)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET e.sales = subquery.sales;
```

---

I don't have enough information to get into details of your logic to fix query above, so here is third option :) (it also may fail, more about it at the bottom):

```
UPDATE payroll.emp_appointments e
SET 
sales = (select w.sales from weekstat w, sysdba.contact_retail c
where 
c.customerid=w.customerid
and cast(w.salespersoncode  as char(6))=e.emp_num
and trunc(e.tradingdate)=w.truncateddate
and e.contactid=c.contactid) 
)
WHERE e.sales=0.00
and and e.tradingdate > sysdate-10
and (e.emp_num, trunc(e.tradingdate), e.contactid)
in 
(select w.salespersoncode, w.truncateddate, c.contactid from 
weekstat w, sysdba.contact_retail c
where c.customerid=w.customerid)
```

I don't like it because you basically repeating logic twice. You might get an error in select after 'sales = ' that it is not returning scale value, but I don't have enough information to address that. So, it will be your responsibility to be sure that that select returns exactly 1 row for any row in table `e` that will be updated.

Also, I removed condition `and e.storecode=cast(e.storecode as varchar2(6))` that looks like redundant.

Comment: Great, thanks the select works, I'm not sure but I got an error message which I haven't seen before "Cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"

Comment: I see, the problem is that I don't think this table has a key, just emp_num which is not nullable that's it though but it is not a key.  Strange but I don't see any keys were put on this table.  What to do in this case, please help?

Comment: I was wrong, you don't need a primary key. It just your query should be "key preserving". Generally, table e rows should not be duplicated. There is another aproach that I will show shortly.

Comment: Okay, great thanks in advance, hoping your next approach will do the trick.

Comment: thanks but it started to think and then gave an error: "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"...

Comment: @vav I assume you are going to fix the MERGE INTO DML statement to remove the typographical error, "MERGE INTO MERGE INTO".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vav, I tried the following and it worked for now:

```
UPDATE payroll.emp_appointments e
SET (e.sales) = (
SELECT w.sumsales
FROM weekstat w, sysdba.contact_retail c
where 
    c.customerid=w.customerid
   and cast(w.salespersoncode  as char(6))=e.emp_num
   and trunc(e.tradingdate)=w.truncateddate
   and e.contactid=c.contactid
   and e.storecode=cast(e.storecode as varchar2(6))
   and e.sales=0.00
   and e.tradingdate > sysdate-10)

where exists (SELECT w.sumsales
FROM weekstat w, sysdba.contact_retail c
where 
    c.customerid=w.customerid
   and cast(w.salespersoncode  as char(6))=e.emp_num
   and trunc(e.tradingdate)=w.truncateddate
   and e.contactid=c.contactid
   and e.storecode=cast(e.storecode as varchar2(6))
   and e.sales=0.00
   and e.tradingdate > sysdate-10)
```